# Prevent pandoc from escaping a characters

Tags: markdown, pandoc, docusaurus

In source markdown (WikiJS format) i have the following element:

```
![](/src/guides/administrator-guide/media/button_dataset.png){height=0.8cm}
```

I need to transform it into an md that can be used in docusaurus. Since docusaurus supports `mdx` it is possible to use html-tags inside *.md code. Something like this:

```
<img src="/src/guides/administrator-guide/media/button_dataset.png" height="0.8cm" />
```

I'm trying to write a custom lua filter to convert source to `img` tag. Like this:

```lua
function Image (elem)
    return '<img src="' .. img.src .. '"' .. 'height="' .. img.attributes.height .. '" />'
end
```

The problem is tha pandoc keeps escaping `<`, `>` and `"` characters so tag cannot be rendered. The output markdown is:

```
\<img
src=\"/src/guides/administrator-guide/media/button_dataset.png\"
/\>
```

Is it possible in pandoc to write string to output markdown document as it is without escaping characters? Maybe there is some option that i need to enable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific problem, a good solution might be to choose `commonmark` instead of pandoc's default Markdown as output format:

```
$ pandoc -t commonmark input.md
<img src="/src/guides/administrator-guide/media/button_dataset.png"
style="height:0.8cm" />
```

However, if you prefer to use a filter, then use `RawInline` elements to avoid escaping:

```lua
function Image (elem)
  return pandoc.RawInline(
    'html',
    string.format('<img src="%s" height="%s" />', img.src, img.attributes.height)
  )
end
```

Comment: Switching to `commonmark` worked, but `img` tag was compiled into regular html adding the `<img src="example.png" style="height: 0.5rem; width: 0.5rem" />`. When processed by docusaurus it results with an error, because docusaurus is using mdx so `style` attribute must be an object `style={{height: '0.5rem', width: '0.5rem'}}`. So i ended up using filter anyway and returning proper jsx tag. The problem is that now it renders tables with tags with other invalid jsx props: `<col style="width: 20%" />`, `<tr class="odd">`, etc. Any way to prevent from processing tables like this?

Comment: Solved by using `gfm` instead of `commonmark`.